# Using AWS-Cloudformatting-Resources with Heat & Openstack in a local cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openstack, aws-cloudformation, heat

We have set up a local cloud-environment with Openstack (essex) and [Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat). But we are confronted with the Problem that we want to add additional files/packages on first boot of an Instance. As far as I know this can be done with [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html).

But when spawning a new instance by executing

> heat create test --template-file=test.template

with the following minimalistic template

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Create and provision a web server",
    "Resources": {
        "NewServer": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "fedora18ami_neu",
                "InstanceType": "m1.large",
                "KeyName": "poc",
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": "#!/bin/sh\n/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s test--region RegionOne -r NewServer\n"
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                    "config": {
                        "packages": {
                            "yum": {
                                "httpd": []
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

we got the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/aws_client.py", line 149, in sign
    derived_key = hmac.new(("AWS4" + creds.secret_key).encode('utf-8'), timestamp_short.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

It seems that cfn-init is trying to connect to some amazon cloud service and needs credentials to perform the action!? Why does it need to connect to Amazon-Services and is there any possibility to avoid it? Or is there another way to get the functionality of [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) implemented in a template? Do I have do declare everything as Shellscript in UserData-Element?

Thx for your help!

Comment: I had no idea HEAT even worked with essex.  You should upgrade your openstack release.  You are about 2 releases out of date.  HEAT will be for the first time actually part of core ( to a degree ) in current release of grizzly.

cfn-init is not a tool I am familiar with.  I cannot guarantee it will work with openstack.  

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html

has documentation on use.  I did note there is a --url parameter that you are not using.  That could be part of your issues.